# How can i make textinput a class variable

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to get TextInput's text from another screen. In the code below I can get the text but my project has multiple functions. So I thought if I can make textinput a class variable it would be eaiser to coding.

Example Code:

**.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import NoTransition
import requests


class MainPage(Screen):
    pass


class ExercisePage(Screen):

    def test(self):
        link = self.manager.get_screen('mainpage')
        a = requests.get(f'{link.ids.http.text}/gpio12On')

    def testt(self):
        link = self.manager.get_screen('mainpage')
        a = requests.get(f'{link.ids.http.text}/gpio12Off')


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        global sm
        sm = ScreenManager(transition=NoTransition())
        sm.add_widget(MainPage(name='mainpage'))
        sm.add_widget(ExercisePage(name='exercisepage'))
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Here is the **.kv** file

```
<MainPage>
    FloatLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: http
            text: ""
            multiline: False
            size_hint: 0.5,0.05
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.3, "y": 0.8}
        Button:
            text:"Enter"
            size_hint: 0.1,0.06
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.82, "y": 0.795}
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "exercisepage"

<ExercisePage>
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text:"test"
            size_hint: 0.5,0.075
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.2, "top": 0.4}
            on_release:
                root.test()
        Button:
            text:"test2"
            size_hint: 0.5,0.075
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.2, "top": 0.5}
            on_release:
                root.testt()
```

What I am trying to do is like this:

```
class ExercisePage(Screen):
    link = self.manager.get_screen('mainpage')
    
    def test(self):
        a = requests.get(f'{self.link.ids.http.text}/gpio12On')

    def testt(self):
        a = requests.get(f'{self.link.ids.http.text}/gpio12Off')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define your application `root` in the `kv` file, then the `ids` are available everywhere in that `root` rule. And then you can define an `ObjectProperty` in the `ExercisePage` that refers to the `TextInput` `text`. Here is what such a `kv` file could look like:

```
ScreenManager:
    MainPage:
        name: 'mainpage'
        FloatLayout:
            TextInput:
                id: http
                text: ""
                multiline: False
                size_hint: 0.5,0.05
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.3, "y": 0.8}
            Button:
                text:"Enter"
                size_hint: 0.1,0.06
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.82, "y": 0.795}
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "exercisepage"  # this could also be just root.current = "exercisepage"
    
    ExercisePage:
        id: escr
        link: http.text  # link to the TextInput text
        name: 'exercisepage'
        FloatLayout:
            Button:
                text:"test"
                size_hint: 0.5,0.075
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.2, "top": 0.4}
                on_release:
                    escr.test()  # changed to use id
            Button:
                text:"test2"
                size_hint: 0.5,0.075
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.2, "top": 0.5}
                on_release:
                    escr.testt()  # changed to use id
```

Then you define the `ObjectProperty` in the `ExercisePage`, and use that in the methods:

```
class ExercisePage(Screen):
    link = ObjectProperty(None)

    def test(self):
        # link = self.manager.get_screen('mainpage')
        print(self.link)
        # a = requests.get(f'{link.ids.http.text}/gpio12On')

    def testt(self):
        # link = self.manager.get_screen('mainpage')
        print(self.link)
        # a = requests.get(f'{link.ids.http.text}/gpio12Off')
```

And since you define the `root` widget in the `kv` file, you can completely eliminate the `build()` method from your `MyApp` class.